Can't connect to SMB share using mount, but works in smbclient on CentOS
I can't connect to an SMB share in the same way that I used to. I used to just be able to mount at \mycompany.corp\dfs but now I have to mount via \my-fileserver.mycompany.corp\dfs
smbclient works as expected though.
When I try to mount an SMB share in CentOS...
mount -t cifs -o user=svc_xxx,domain=mycompany.corp,vers=2.1 //mycompany.corp/dfs /mnt/tmp
I get the following error:
[48785.947248] CIFS VFS: BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\mycompany.corp\dfs
[48785.949836] CIFS VFS: session ffff9a43e7236000 has no tcon available for a dfs referral request
[48785.952675] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2

But when I do it in smbclient, it works.
smbclient \\\\mycompany.corp\\dfs -U 'mycompany.corp\svc_xxx' -m SMB2
If I list the servers in smbclient, I get:
smb: \> list 0:      server=my-fileserver.mycompany.corp, share=dfs 
mycompany.corp doesn't resolve to what my-fileserver.mycompany.corp resolves to.
The strange thing though is if I use mount with the name of the fileserver, i.e.:
mount -t cifs -o user=svc_xxx,domain=mycompany.corp,vers=2.1 //my-fileserver.mycompany.corp/dfs /mnt/tmp
...it works.
How does smbclient 'know' how to connect to mycompany.corp but mount doesn't? Any why would it suddenly break (there were some changes to our LDAP controllers and DNS servers, but I don't have specifics).
